# Does it exist a function such that $f(x)-f(y) > (x-y)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Does it exist a function $f$ such that
$$f(x)-f(y)> (x-y)^2 $$
with
$$x,y\in (0,1)$$
If it exist can one give me an example?

Comment: Do you think $x-y > (x-y)^2$ for $x,y \in (0,1)$?

Comment: well it seems unlikely that both $f(x) - f(y) > (x - y)^2$ and $f(y) - f(x) > (x - y)^2$. Maybe you could ask about $\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert$ : )

Comment: @GEdgar:  I don't understand your point.  The fact that $f(x) = x$ does not satisfy the OP's conditions says nothing about whether any of an infinite number of other functions might.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible.  Set $x = y$ to see this.

Answer (score 2):

Following Izaak van Dongen's suggestion, let's assume that you want the version of the inequality with absolute values. And following David G. Stork's answer, let's assume that we only need the inequality for $x\neq y$, so that $|x-y|>0$.

For all $x,y\in(0,1)$, we have $|x-y|<1$, so $(x-y)^2<|x-y|$.

To take advantage of the above, just let $f(x)=x$. Then $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|>(x-y)^2$.